# Finding vector length based on parallell and orthogonal vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Do anyone know a simple way of finding the length of vector a in my figure? The known values are $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$. (If you look closely, you can see that $f$-vector is a force, and that I need to find the arm between force and point $3$, to calculate the momentum.)
[image: Vector image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ then you can find the equation of line passes through these points. Suppose you find its equation as $y=mx+n$ then you can also find equation of line passes through $(x_2,y_2)$ because you know its slope $\frac{-1}m$, suppose you found it as $y=\frac{-1}{m}x+k$. Now you know already the slope of line passes through $(x_3,y_3)$ so you can find the equation of it either, suppose it is $y=mx+l$. If you solve the equations $y=\frac{-1}{m}x+k$ and $y=mx+l$ you will find a point $(x_4,y_4)$. After that you can find the length of vector by the following formula $$\sqrt{(x_3-x_4)^2+(y_3-y_4)^2}$$